# Zend_Filter_Input and required value

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to make an array item required when using `Zend_Filter_Input`:

```
    $data = array();
    $validators = array(
        'name' => 'NotEmpty'
    );
    $filters = array(
        '*' => 'StringTrim'
    );

    $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $data);

    var_dump($input->isValid());
```

It returns `true`, while I expect it to be `false`.

Any ways of doing that?

**UPD**:

found it:

```
$validators = array(
    'name' => array(
        'NotEmpty',
        'presence' => 'required' // <-----
    )
);
```

but for non existing value `$input->getErrors();` returns empty array. How to retrieve a proper error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if (!$input->isValid()) {
    $errors = $input->getMessages();
}
```

Comment: Wondering how I missed that method o_O

Comment: Btw, is there a way to change a message for `required`?

Comment: as usual for forms I guess array('messages'=> array('missingMessage' => 'blabla'));

Comment: tried that and it leads to `No message template exists for key 'missingMessage'` exception

Comment: sorry, you are right have a look in `setOptions(array $options)` method on line :558 case `self::MISSING_MESSAGE:`